# How to deploy two different raills application in AWS OpsWorks

Tags: aws-opsworks

I am running my rails application on OpsWorks already, now i wanted to run another new rails application on the OpsWorks. For that I have created an new app and added to the existing instance, The deployment was successful but I am not able to find out the way to access my new rails application, any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Could you describe in more details how you set up a new app, how it is different from the existing app in terms of set up, and what were your criterias to define deployment as successful?

Comment: Configuration settings are same for both the applications like both the applications are Rails 4.x.

One application is like user portal and another application is admin portal. Both the apps are using same db.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you created an ***Rails Application Server layer***, and under that you created two ***Apps*** for the each of your apps, then you should be setting the **Domain Name** in each of the app's settings (bottom), i.e. myapp.mydomain.com and myapp-admin.mydomain.com. Then you need to set up your DNS to point to your public IP, i.e. in Route 53 create A records with the Alias setting that points to the correct server in the pull-down option menu.